# RedBean ORM and Codeigniter, how to make Fuse recognize models loaded from CI default models path?

Tags: codeigniter, orm

Codeigniter has its own Models path, where models extend from CI_Model. I'm using RedBean has a library in Codeigniter, loading it on a controller. After loading Rb, I try to use CI Loader to load a model that extends redbean_simplemodel (wish works, there's no error), but the events / methods inside the model have no effect when they're called on bean.

For example,
APPPATH/application/libraries/rb.php

```
class Rb {

    function __construct()
    {
        // Include database configuration
        include(APPPATH.'/config/database.php');

        // Get Redbean
        include(APPPATH.'/third_party/rb/rb.php');

        // Database data
        $host = $db[$active_group]['hostname'];
        $user = $db[$active_group]['username'];
        $pass = $db[$active_group]['password'];
        $db   = $db[$active_group]['database'];

        // Setup DB connection
        R::setup("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pass);

    } //end __contruct()


} //end Rb
```

And then on
APPPATH/application/models/model_song.php

```
class Model_song extends RedBean_SimpleModel {

 public function store() {
  if ( $this->title != 'test' ) {
  throw new Exception("Illegal title, not equal «test»!");
  }
 }

}
```

while on 
APPPATH/application/controllers/welcome.php

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('rb');
        $this->load->model('model_song');

        $song = R::dispense('song');
        $song->title  = 'bluuuh';
        $song->track = 4;
        $id = R::store($song);
        echo $id;

    }
}
```

My question is, how to make RedBean (FUSE http://redbeanphp.com/#/Fuse) work on Codeigniter ?

Thanks for looking!

**----- FOUND SOLUTION!**

Actually, it's working! I was trying to place code under my model, method store(). That wont work! I tryed to place a new method called update() and it does work! Check the example below:

```
class Model_song extends RedBean_SimpleModel {

 public function update() {
  if ( $this->title != 'test' ) {
    throw new Exception("Illegal title!");
  }
 }

}
```

The solution is the following:

"Assuming that you've already installed RedBean on Codeigniter"

1) Load the library for «redbean»
 2) Using ci_loader, load the desired model (the model must extend redbean_simplemodel)

Thanks for looking! I hope this helps other people too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is the following:

"Assuming that you've already installed RedBean on Codeigniter"

1. Load the library for «redbean»
2. Using ci_loader, load the desired model (the model must extend redbean_simplemodel)