# CodeIgniter, RedBeanPHP and FUSE - Models not recognized by FUSE

Tags: codeigniter, orm

I too ran into the problem that FUSE won't work with CI and RBphp.

in APPPATH/application/core/ I have a base model called "MY_Model.php"

```
class MY_Model {}
class Base extends RedBean_SimpleModel {
  // static methods 
}
```

I have a derived class, like this, called "model_user.php" in APPPATH/application/models/:

```
class Model_User extends Base {
    public function getData() {
        return $this->bean->id;
    }
}
```

And in the controller I load the model:

```
$this->load->model('Model_User');
```

The rb library is autoloaded via the autoload.php file.

After creating an object of the type Model_User with redbean, I still cannot access the getData() method.

I already read this question + answer asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457774/redbean-orm-and-codeigniter-how-to-make-fuse-recognize-models-loaded-from-ci-de/26512905#26512905), but they didn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was due to the naming convention. Whilst the table itself was called "users", the bean's name was "Model_User". So RedBean was looking for a "User" table in the database. Renaming the class to Model_Users, or renaming the table to "user" was the solution.